# does the MB need to offer graphics support in order to run iGPU?

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer, integrated-graphics, amd-graphics-card

i’m looking to build an office pc for my dad. cpu should be amd 3000G with its integrated graphics. some mainboards advertise “vega graphics support” so exactly what i would need. then again, others say there’s no integrated graphics. is this really something different, or just a different way of saying you either need gpu on cpu our a video card? i was looking to get the MSI A320M-A Pro but i’m not sure if it demands a video card, which i’d hesitate to buy.
somehow i can’t seem to find the answer online. thank you in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but most x86 CPUs have basic graphics cards on them. If a motherboard claims no integrated graphics it may not be exposing them on the motherboard and may require an external GPU to start.  VESA is a very simple graphics standard that I'm sure any graphics card usable in modern hardware can provide.

Comment: the question basically is if amd vega graphics cpus have a special requirement for mbs, apart from socket, video plug. i dont want a video card. @davidgo

Answer (score 0):

On modern hardware the iGPU is integrated into CPU. Motherboard only provides video outputs (HDMI, DVI or VGA). If a motherboard has any video output and CPU has iGPU (some don't), it will work.

This was not the case with older (pre-2010) hardware, where iGPUs were provided solely by the motherboard.

All in all, if you have any video outputs on the motherboard, it has iGPU support.

Comment: just thought about that, it indeed has VGA so it should work.

Comment: so actually “vega graphics support” is kinda misleading...